# compile error with rows.next() in GRDB and Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, grdb

I am developing an iOS app using Swift 3 and the GRDB SQLite library. The following code fragment causes a compile error of "value of type '[Row]' has no member 'next'"

```
let rows = try Row.fetchAll(db, sql, arguments:arguments)
while let row = try rows.next() {             <--- line with error
      ...
}
```

As far as I can tell I am following the example in the docs correctly. 
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: fetchCursor gives next() not fetchAll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetchAll` method returns a regular Swift array, that you iterate like all other arrays:

```
let rows = try Row.fetchAll(db, sql, arguments:arguments) // [Row]
for row in rows {
    // use row
}
```

The `next` method belongs to *cursors*, that you get with the `fetchCursor` method. Cursors are not arrays because they don't load all database results in one step. Instead, cursors are iterated row after row:

```
let rows = try Row.fetchCursor(db, sql, arguments:arguments) // DatabaseCursor<Row>
while let row = try rows.next() {
    // use row
}
```

You see that both arrays and cursors can iterate database results. How do you choose one or the other? Look at the differences:

- Arrays contain copies of database values and may be consumed on any thread.
- Arrays can can take a lot of memory, if the number of fetched results is high.
- Arrays can be iterated many times.
- Cursors iterate over database results in a lazy fashion, and don't consume much memory.
- Cursors are faster because they go straight to SQLite and don't copy database values unless necessary.
- Cursors can not be used on any thread.
- Cursors can be iterated only one time.

Compare:

```
// On the main thread:
let (rowArray, rowCursor) = try dbQueue.inDatabase { db -> ([Row], DatabaseCursor<Row>) in
    let rowArray = try Row.fetchAll(db, "SELECT ...")
    let rowCursor = try Row.fetchCursor(db, "SELECT ...")

    // OK
    for row in rowArray { ... }
    while let row = try rowCursor.next() { ... }

    // Second iteration
    for row in rowArray { ... }                  // the same rows
    while let row = try rowCursor.next() { ... } // no result

    return (rowArray, rowCursor)
}

// OK: arrays can be consumed on any thread
for row in rowArray { ... }
DispatchQueue.global(.default).async {
    for row in rowArray { ... }
}

// DON'T DO THAT, NEVER
while let row = try rowCursor.next() { ... }
DispatchQueue.global(.default).async {
    while let row = try rowCursor.next() { ... }
}
```

If you don't see, or don't care about the difference, use arrays. If you care about memory and performance, use cursors when appropriate.

Link to the documentation: https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/README.md#fetching-methods